# Boot Mgt Missing

Tags: external-hard-drive, operating-systems

I have a Vista OS on my Toshiba A305-S683243. I did a complete reformat of the Hard drive. The recovery disks from Toshiba and the most recently purchased one both give me the message "boot management missing" and in a few words asks me to try again with the same result. I need some suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, it's unclear what your asking can you review [ask] and try and re-word it so it's clearer for the community?

Answer (score 0):

A master boot record (MBR) is a special type of boot sector at the very beginning of partitioned computer mass storage devices like fixed disks or removable drives.You can format partitions using different utilities like diskpart,parition manager in windows ,but you may have to use special utilities to rewrite or remove executable code from your MBR.

In your case, i guess , you have effectively managed to format partitions , but since you haven't cleared your MBR ,at the boot time,it's showing a "Boot Mgr Missing".

You don't have to bother about this error because the MBR will automatically be rewritten when you install the new OS.

This article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) will provide you insights into understanding more about MBR and how to repair them.